# Get all tags of a HTML with bs4

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to be able to get all tags of a HTML file, say:

```
<html>
<body>
<something>
</something>
</body>
</html>
```

I want this to return something like: `['html', 'body', 'something']`
While bs4 is able to get all instances of a tag, I'm yet to find anything that can return
all tags. This is the code I wrote to return a clean output.

```
with open('nameofhtm.html') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')     
    print(soup.prettify())

Output:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>
   nothing
  </title>
  <link href="None" rel="shortcut icon"/>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <header>
   nothing more
  </header>
  <something>
  </something>
 </head>
</html>
```

Is there a way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For this example you wrote, what would be the exact expected output?

Comment: The expected output is `['html', 'head', 'title', 'header', 'something']`. It doesn't matter if `'meta'` and `'link'` come up too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a filter function and extract all the tag names:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html)
tag_names = [tag.name for tag in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag is not None)]
```

One could just as well use `soup.find_all(name=True)` to search for all tags with any tag name, i.e.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html)
tag_names = [tag.name for tag in soup.find_all(name=True)]
```

which is equivalent to the filter function.